# Problem with TO_INTEGER in VHDL I can't find a solution

Tags: vhdl

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY mult4 IS
    PORT (
        a, b : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
        cout : OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END mult4;

ARCHITECTURE behave OF mult4 IS
    SIGNAL result : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    arith_process : PROCESS (a, b)
        VARIABLE p : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 255;

    BEGIN
        p := TO_INTEGER ('0' & a) * TO_INTEGER('0' & b);
        result <= TO_STDLOGICVECTOR(p, 8);
    END PROCESS arith_process;
    cout <= result;
END behave;
```

I'm having a problem with TO_INTEGER, I tried to fix it but none worked, I'm new to VHDL and I'm not finding the solution.

Error (10405): VHDL error at mult4.vhd(19): can't determine type of object at or near identifier "TO_INTEGER" -- found 0 possible types

Comment: `'0' & a` The type of a is std_logic_vector, it's element base type is std_ulogic, the concatenation operator is predefined for any single dimensional array type and it's element type. The result type is of the array type. There is no visible declaration of `to_integer` with an operand type of std_logic_vector. Here type convert `to_integer(unsigned('0' & a))` std_logic_vector is closely rated to unsigned. You shouldn't use use clauses making declarations from IEEE package numeric_std and Synopsys package std_logic_arith together. Their type declarations are distinct.